# Openstack cannot attach volume to instance

Tags: openstack, cinder

I try to install block storage, but the volume cannot attach to instance.
I'm pretty sure, I followed all instructions but compute node got error

```
    2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 ERROR oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-c9a73cff-03f4-4475-8f71-45f066407376 ] Exception during message handling: iSCSI device not found at /dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.10.10.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-98600992-0642-428a-8e3e-4486234455b2-lun-1
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 134, in _dispatch_and_reply
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     incoming.message))
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 177, in _dispatch
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 123, in _do_dispatch
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = getattr(endpoint, method)(ctxt, **new_args)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 414, in decorated_function
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception.py", line 88, in wrapped
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     payload)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 82, in __exit__
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception.py", line 71, in wrapped
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(self, context, *args, **kw)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 298, in decorated_function
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     pass
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 82, in __exit__
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 284, in decorated_function
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 326, in decorated_function
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     kwargs['instance'], e, sys.exc_info())
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 82, in __exit__
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 314, in decorated_function
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4536, in attach_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     do_attach_volume(context, instance, driver_bdm)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/lockutils.py", line 272, in inner
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4534, in do_attach_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     bdm.destroy(context)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 82, in __exit__
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4531, in do_attach_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return self._attach_volume(context, instance, driver_bdm)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4554, in _attach_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self.volume_api.unreserve_volume(context, bdm.volume_id)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 82, in __exit__
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4546, in _attach_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     do_check_attach=False, do_driver_attach=True)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 46, in wrapped
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     ret_val = method(obj, context, *args, **kwargs)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 261, in attach
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     connector)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 82, in __exit__
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 252, in attach
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     device_type=self['device_type'], encryption=encryption)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1380, in attach_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     conf = self._connect_volume(connection_info, disk_info)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1327, in _connect_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return driver.connect_volume(connection_info, disk_info)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/lockutils.py", line 272, in inner
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/volume.py", line 310, in connect_volume
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher     % (host_device))
2014-11-04 17:25:05.265 20896 TRACE oslo.messaging.rpc.dispatcher NovaException: iSCSI device not found at /dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.10.10.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-98600992-0642-428a-8e3e-4486234455b2-lun-1
```

tgt-admin -s (controller node as storage node)

```
Target 2: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-98600992-0642-428a-8e3e-4486234455b2
    System information:
        Driver: iscsi
        State: ready
    I_T nexus information:
        I_T nexus: 3
            Initiator: iqn.1993-08.org.debian:01:ccb03be69ac3 alias: compute1
            Connection: 0
                IP Address: 10.10.10.101
    LUN information:
        LUN: 0
            Type: controller
            SCSI ID: IET     00020000
            SCSI SN: beaf20
            Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            SWP: No
            Thin-provisioning: No
            Backing store type: null
            Backing store path: None
            Backing store flags: 
        LUN: 1
            Type: disk
            SCSI ID: IET     00020001
            SCSI SN: beaf21
            Size: 2147 MB, Block size: 512
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            SWP: No
            Thin-provisioning: No
            Backing store type: rdwr
            Backing store path: /dev/cinder-volumes/volume-98600992-0642-428a-8e3e-4486234455b2
            Backing store flags: 
    Account information:
        ypRS2YzBswJE48k6bGs9
    ACL information:
        ALL
```

iscsiadm -m session (compute node)

```
tcp: [29] 10.10.10.1:3260,1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-98600992-0642-428a-8e3e-4486234455b2
```

ls -al /dev/disk/by-path/ (compute node)

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov  4 14:58 pci-0000:16:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov  4 14:58 pci-0000:16:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov  4 14:58 pci-0000:16:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov  4 14:58 pci-0000:16:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part3 -> ../../sda3
```

Openstack: Juno
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (Controller node as storage node) and Ubuntu 14.10 (Compute node), this is problem?
Very appreciate your help...I was worked for it for days...T__T

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: Nova is looking for an iSCSI target at 10.10.10.1, but your iSCSI target has the IP address 10.10.10.101.

Comment: I use tgt on controller node (as storage node) with ip 10.10.10.1 and my compute node ip is 10.10.10.101, so how to change nova to search from 10.10.10.101